# how to add the incremented integer for a duplicate value of a property when 2 nodes have same property value in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

In my neo4j, I have a node "Blog" which has property "Title".And the "Title" property could have same value for 2 different Blog nodes. For e.g.

```
    Blog 
   {
    "Id": 1
    "Title":"Apple"
   },
   {
    "Id": 2
    "Title":"Apple"
    }
```

So, although the Id may be unique, but the "Title"property could have same exact value "**Apple**".And if the same value is present, then in that case I want to add a number at the end to the value(present in Title property) for the latter node like "**Apple 1**",Apple 2.....
**Here is my latest code...**

```
Merge (D:Blog{ID:3})set D.Title = "Apple" with D
    // Collect all blogs with duplicate titles
MATCH (T:Blog)
WITH T.Title as title, 
     collect(distinct T) as blogs WHERE size(blogs) > 1

// Calculate the possible maximum start index for the title
OPTIONAL MATCH (T:Blog) 
WHERE size(T.Title) > size(title) AND T.Title STARTS WITH title
WITH title, 
     blogs,
     max(
       coalesce(
         toInteger(trim(
           substring(T.Title, size(title))
         )),
         0
       )
     ) + 1 as startIndex

// Rename all blogs except the first
UNWIND RANGE(1, size(blogs)-1) as i
WITH title + ' ' + (startIndex + i) as newTitle,
     blogs[i] as blog
SET blog.Title = newTitle
RETURN blog
```

What should I do in the cypher query to perform this execution ? I looked into apoc.do.when but I was unable to figure it out.Any help would be appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get all blogs
MATCH (T1:Blog)
WITH T1.Title AS title, 
     // Then we collect all the blogs with the same titles, 
     // and remove the first one from the collection
     TAIL( COLLECT(DISTINCT T1) ) AS blogs
// Then we need to go through the cycle for the remaining blogs in the collection
UNWIND RANGE(1, size(blogs)) AS index
WITH title, 
     blogs[index] as blog,
     index
// And rename...
SET blog.Title= title+ ' ' + index
RETURN name, 
       blog
```

**Update** | Solution of the problem with comments from the [@InverseFalcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92359/inversefalcon):

```
// Collect all blogs with duplicate titles
MATCH (T:Blog)
WITH T.Title as title, 
     collect(distinct T) as blogs WHERE size(blogs) > 1

// Calculate the possible maximum start index for the title
OPTIONAL MATCH (T:Blog) 
WHERE size(T.Title) > size(title) AND T.Title STARTS WITH title
WITH title, 
     blogs,
     max(
       coalesce(
         toInteger(trim(
           substring(T.Title, size(title))
         )),
         0
       )
     ) + 1 as startIndex

// Rename all blogs except the first
UNWIND RANGE(1, size(blogs)-1) as i
WITH title + ' ' + (startIndex + i) as newTitle,
     blogs[i] as blog
SET blog.Title = newTitle
RETURN blog
```

Comment: Keep in mind this approach only works well the first time executed. But let's say later on, after you have "Apple" and numbered apples through 50, you add another "Apple" titled-blog. That will change it to "Apple1", and now you have 2 Apple 1's. Run it again, and it will detect the two "Apple1" titled blogs and change one of them to "Apple11".

Comment: Thanks both of you !!, It worked @stdob...But when I tried first to add a new Blog (using MERGE) with same title along with the above query, it seems to be working only for 2 nodes. could you please let me know what i am doing wrong? I have added my code above.

Comment: @CodeReactor You need to add your code to the original post, but not to my answer.

Comment: @stdob have updated the code on my original post. could you please help me out here ? thanks in advance

Comment: I have updated my errored code above in the original post.I have tried all ways, but still unable to create and update the validation through same query, could you please help me out here ?